# Vc++ 2015 No command window appears after executing program

Tags: visual-c++

I'm brand new to programming, so this could be an easy fix.

Basically, when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to build and launch my code, Visual Studio 2015 locks up, replaces my mouse cursor with a spinning circle, and doesn't display the command prompt window.

I've tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but all that does is display a blank command prompt window, and I've also tried using the `system("pause");` command to force it to stop the code after it executes.

Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please show the (relevant) code? Otherwise we have to guess what happend...

Comment: Do you have Avast! antivirus installed, by any chance? Lots of reports of Avast interfering with Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to respond after I sorted out my issue yesterday. I posted the same question in the Microsoft Visual Studio forums yesterday as well, and I got a response saying that I need to disable Avast. That was definitely the problem and now everything works just fine.